# Updating only those properties are changed

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geocoding, mapbox

I am plotting LineStrings in Mapbox.So now I am updating the color of the lines when the property is changed.

```
function update_the_map(){
  $.ajax({ 
    url:"http://dataurl",
    contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    type: "GET",
    dataformat:"JSON",
    async : false,
    success: function(data){ 

        for (i = 0; i <lines.features.length; i++) { 
            lines['features'][i]['properties']['points']=data[i].points;
            var style_update =getColor( lines['features'][i]['properties']['points']); 
            geojson.setFeatureStyle(lines['features'][i]['properties']['id'], style_update);
        }

        setTimeout( update_the_map, 10000);
        console.log("updated");
    },
    error:function(){}  
  });
}
```

But this changes all the color of the lines and not those points are greater than 5.Because my get color function is like

```
function getColor(d) {
           if(d==10 || d==9 || d==8  || d==7  || d==6){
               return '#ff0000';
           }
           else {
               return '#00a1ff';
           }
    }
```

So it returns red if points>5 else it returns blue.But this returns blue for everything and the whole lines color is changed.ANy help is appreciated.This is how i create the layer.

```
geojson = L.vectorGrid.slicer(lines, {
    vectorTileLayerStyles: {
        sliced: style},

    maxZoom: 24, // max zoom to preserve detail on
    interactive: true,
    getFeatureId: function(f) {
        return f.properties.id;
    }
}).on('mouseover', mouseover_function).addTo(map);
```

My lines is a variable as below :

```
 var lines= {

            "type":"FeatureCollection","features": [{"type": "Feature","geometry":{"type":"LineString", 
"coordinates":[[ 101.942139,4.252606],[101.766357,3.134346]]},
"properties": {"id":"01","points":10}},....
    ]};
```

Comment: When you create the layer, what's the value of `links` and `style`??

Comment: When I create the layer all the points are 10 . So every line is red. After 10 seconds they change So which have >5 gets red then <5 gets blue. But now I debugged the color I get at `var style_update =getColor( lines['features'][i]['properties']['points']);`  It is according to the points. So I think i am wrong somewhere setting the style of the line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following did make the update work like a charm. So insteading of passing only the color I passed the weight and opacity and color It worked fine.

```
function update_the_map(){
      $.ajax({ 
        url:"http://dataurl",
        contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        type: "GET",
        dataformat:"JSON",
        async : false,
        success: function(data){ 
             var style_update; //changed declaration here

        for (i = 0; i <lines.features.length; i++) { 
            lines['features'][i]['properties']['points']=data[i].points;
            style_update = {
                                            weight: 2,
                                            opacity: 1,                                             
                                            color: getColor(links['features'][i]['properties']['score']),                                                                           
                                            fillOpacity: 0.7
                           };//added this whole for variable style update

 geojson.setFeatureStyle(links['features'][i]['properties']['id'],style_update);
                                                    }

        setTimeout( update_the_map, 10000);
        console.log("updated");
    },
    error:function(){}  
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you show that what is inside the line.features array OR check the value of d in console, passed to getColor function.

Comment: When I print what color do they get when passed to  getColor function They are getting colors as per the score.(Like `9 is the points passed to get red,3 is the score passed to get blue,9 is the score passed to get red` ). So this clarifies the error is while plotting the color only. Because each time I get the correct color as per the points but when I try to set style according to the color somewhere I am doing the mistake.